# Non-linear first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to solve a PDE

$x (u_x)^2 + u_y = y $

$u(x,0)=x$

using the method of characteristics (i.e. $p=u_x$, $q=u_y$ and the above PDE is $xp^2+q-y=0$. I have tried so many times but just cant get it! Help would be appreciated!

Comment: The next thing to do is to write out the characteristic equations.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but I know I am not doing it correctly, I get

$x'(s)=2xp$, $y'(s)=1$, $u'(s)=2xp^2+q$, $p'(s)=-2p^2$, $q'(s)=1$

I think I am doing something wrong with my intiial condition for p and q

Comment: Am i correct in saying $p(0)=1$ and $q(0)=-x(0)p(0)^2$ as $y(0)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
x\pars{\mrm{u}_{x}}^{2} + \,\mrm{u}_{y} = y \implies
\bbx{\ds{x\pars{\varphi_{x}}^{2} + \,\varphi_{y} = 0}}\,,\quad
\varphi\pars{x,y} \equiv \,\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} - {1 \over 2}\,y^{2}\,,\quad
\varphi\pars{x,0} = x 
\end{align}

---

$$
0 = x\,\mrm{f}'^{2}\pars{x}\,\mrm{g}^{2}\pars{y} + \,\mrm{f}\pars{x}\,\mrm{g}'\pars{y} \implies
x\,{\mrm{f}'^{2}\pars{x} \over \mrm{f}\pars{x}} = -\,{\mrm{g}'\pars{y} \over \,\mrm{g}^{2}\pars{y}} = \mu
$$

---

$$
{\mrm{f}'\pars{x} \over \mrm{f}^{1/2}\pars{x}} = {\root{\mu} \over x^{1/2}}\,,
\quad
{\mrm{g}'\pars{y} \over \mrm{g}^{2}\pars{y}} = -\mu
$$

---

$$
2\,\mrm{f}^{1/2}\pars{x} = 2\root{\mu}x^{1/2} + 2a
\quad
-\,{1 \over \mrm{g}\pars{y}} = -\mu y - b
$$

---

\begin{align}
\varphi\pars{x,y} & = {\pars{\root{\mu}x^{1/2} + a}^{2} \over \mu y + b} =
{\mu x + 2a\root{\mu}x^{1/2} + a^{2} \over \mu y + b}\implies
x = \varphi\pars{x,0} = 
{\mu x + 2a\root{\mu}x^{1/2} + a^{2} \over b}
\\[5mm] \implies & b = \mu\,,\quad a = 0
\implies \varphi\pars{x} = {x \over y + 1}\implies
\bbx{\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,y} = {x \over y + 1} + {1 \over 2}\,y^{2}}}
\end{align}